# How to allow regex only for numbers and logical operators (actually works only with numbers)

Tags: javascript, regex, logical-operators

I'm trying implements a regex on input to allow ONLY numbers and logical operators(`>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=`).

With this code I can allow only numbers. I tried to do some modifications to allow logical operatos too but without successful.

My Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $('#txt').on("keyup", function (event) {
    if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]|^0+(?!$)/g, '');
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Somoeone can help me?

How I can modify my regex to allow only numbers and logical operators(`>`, `<`, `>=` and `<=`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex change below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txt').on("keyup", function(event) {
    if (/[\D\>\<\=]/g.test(this.value)) {
      this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\>\<\=]|^0+(?!$)/g, '');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt">
```

Comment: Very simple. Thanks a lot guy!